# Use or install different versions of python3 pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install packages for my python 3.5.0 versus my python 3.4.3

I can run both by typing either `python3.4` or `python3.5`

I have `pip2` and `pip3`. I also ran the script `sudo easy_install3 pip`, which made me be able to use `pip3.4` But I am still having trouble installing modules for python3.5. `pip3` just installs for python3.4

I am looking to install termcolor for python3.5 and I am having no success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows, and you appear not to be, but maybe the following will help.

If `pip` is in your system's equivalent of `python35/Lib/site-packages`, then `python3.5 -m pip` should run `pip` so that it installs into the 3.5 site-packages.

If you do not have pip in the 3.5 site-packages, copy its directory, along with its dependencies (pip....dist-info/, setuptools/, setuptools....dist-info/, and easyinstall.py) from the 3.4 site_packages.

Or, if pip3 or even pip3.4 is in `python35/Scripts`, run it with its full path name so you are not running the 3.4 version.